# Finding the flaw in $-12=(-12)^1=(-12)^{6/6}=\cdots=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, roots, fake-proofs

I was tutoring today and came across a question that I was incapable of explaining sufficiently. It stems from the following false string of equalities...

$$-12=(-12)^1=(-12)^\frac{6}{6} =((-12)^6)^\frac{1}{6} =((-1)^6 12^6)^\frac{1}{6}=(12^6)^\frac{1}{6}=12$$

If anyone can explain the false step (Im assuming the third “=“), why this string of equalities is wrong, and how to avoid making it that would be most helpful for when I need to explain it again.

Comment: At the last step there are many choices for the $6$-root...

Comment: Similar question has been asked many times ,the thing is $a^{bc}={(a^b)}^c$ need not be valid

Comment: Also a similar problem posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907035/what-is-1-frac13/3907045#3907045)

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Answer (score 0):

> $-12=(-12)^1=(-12)^\frac{6}{6} =((-12)^6)^\frac{1}{6}$

Last step above is wrong, because of the arbitrary convention that a positive number (i.e. $[(-12)^6]$) when taken to the $(1/6)$ power is equal to a positive number, not a negative number.